# Calculating DATETIME into MINUTES FOR SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have two columns as datetime (2017-02-27 09:20:30.000 & 2017-02-27 09:27:27.000) which I have a new column for that brings in the difference as the result however the results seem to be incorrect.

For instance the result I received was "1445" instead of "7"

The formula below is what I have entered where (Start Timestamp) and (CG Case Submission) are the datetime I am trying to test.

```
,'TURNAROUND' = DATEPART(DAY, PE.[Start Timestamp] 
         - PG.[CG Case Submission Time]) *24*60 
         + DATEPART(HOUR, PE.[Start Timestamp] 
         - PG.[CG Case Submission Time]) *60 
         + DATEPART(MINUTE, PE.[Start Timestamp] 
         - PG.[CG Case Submission Time])
```

Any assistance will be greatly welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

To get the difference in `Minute` you can use this :

```
select datediff(MINUTE, '2017-02-27 09:20:30.000', '2017-02-27 09:27:27.000')
```

It's output is `7`